# how to use stream onDone

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to navigate after stream done. Is there any way to use it? 
onDone is never calling(stream is never done. How to fix this?)

```
  _db.getIsApplied(v.user.uid).listen((data){
    if(data.isApplied == 'Y'){
      if(!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        path = '/homePage';
      });
    }else{
      if(!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        path = '/accountInfoPage';
      });
    }

  },
     onDone: () {
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
       path, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
 }, onError: (error) {
   print("Some Error");
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onDone` method is called when the `Stream` closes:

> If this stream closes and sends a done event, the onDone handler is
>   called

[Stream - listen method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Stream/listen.html)

You could make the navigation call when you get the data. But the purpose of `Stream` is to use it if you need to get data multiple times, and here it seems that you just need it once to then open a new screen, so you could use a `Future` instead.